# watch grep on file doesn't work properly

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to grep a string with spaces on file, the grep it self works great with this command:

```
grep ": error" makeErr.txt

...results as expected...
```

now I'm trying to put this command inside watch and it doesn't work:

```
watch 1 'grep ": error:" makeErr.txt'

> grep ": error:" makeErr.txt

grep: error:": No such file or directory
```

It supposedly trying to run `grep ": error:" makeErr.txt` which is the right command, but for some reason it results in an error.
I tried a lot of quotes variations but all results are the same.
How do I do it properly?

Comment: Remove the external quotes `watch grep "foo bar" baz.txt`

Comment: @Mat is I run this: watch 1 grep "foo bar" baz.txt I get > grep
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...

Comment: cantOS, it appears I did alias for watch long ago and forgot about it. sorry to bother.

Comment: why be sorry? that's exactly the kind of thing that happens to everybody now and then and when you need a fresh pair of eyes. glad we could help ;)

Comment: it's just that it's my mistake that probably never gonna apply to anybody else, so anyone who will come here will find it useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to specify an update interval of 1 second, you need to use the `-n` switch. Otherwise, you don't need any quotes around the rest of the command:

```
watch -n 1 grep ": error:" makeErr.txt
```

Comment: > 1

/home/vlad/watch.sh: line 6: 1: command not found
sleep: invalid option -- 'n'
Try `sleep --help' for more information.

Comment: There's no call to `sleep` in the line in my answer, so that's a separate issue

Comment: @Vladp: where does `watch.sh` come from, and what's it doing in your path?

Comment: what is the output of which watch && watch --version

Comment: indeed it was my fault, I forgot I overwrote watch with an alias and that is where all my troubles are coming from. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

if the output of

```
  which watch && watch --version
```

is something like this:

```
/usr/bin/watch
watch from procps-ng 3.3.10
```

then you need to enclose it it in '', because watch causes the command to be run via sh -c.

```
 watch -n 1 'grep ": error" makeErr.txt'
```

maybe running

```
tail -f makeErr.txt | grep ": error"
```

would be an alternative to watch